# Hide Tablix on Condition base in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-expression

I've one main report in which I have created two different Tablix. (Both have different dataset)

My question is, How can I hide tablix on condition base in SSRS.

***For example:***

`Parameters!First.Value="Y"` then hide only **`first tablix`** and show **`second tablix`** but if `Parameters!First="Y" AND Parameters!Second.Value="Y"` then show only **`first tablix`** not the **`second one`**.

*How can I achieve this, Please help.*

Comment: I assume you tried setting the visibility / hidden property of the tablixes... What equation did you put in there?

Comment: Yes I've tried like this as per my condition, `=IIF(Parameters!First.Value="Y",False,True)` but the main problem is how can I hide other tablix from this expression?

Comment: You need to put conditions in both tablixes.

Comment: I've tried but we have one common condition here is `Parameters!First.Value="Y"` so it is showing both tablix in such condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Tablix Visibility/Hidden Expression

```
=Parameters!First.Value="Y" AND NOT(Parameters!Second.Value="Y")
```

OR

```
=Parameters!First.Value="Y" AND (Parameters!Second.Value<>"Y" OR ISNOTHING(Parameters!Second.Value))
```

OR

```
=IIF(Parameters!First.Value="Y" AND Parameters!Second.Value="Y",False,True)
```

Second Tablix Visibility/Hidden Expression:

```
=Parameters!First.Value="Y" AND Parameters!Second.Value="Y"
```

OR

```
=iif(Parameters!First.Value="Y" AND Parameters!Second.Value="Y", True, False)
```

First evaluate both hidden expression independtly.

**Note:** For expression in SSRS you can write a shortcut expression without using iif.